# Copy group of folders with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have been working on this project for my job, which involves backing up selected information from a computer to one of our servers. So far I have posted a couple of questions and gotten a lot of valuable help, so thanks everyone for that! The current bug that I have hit is when attempting to duplicate a selection involving multiple errors. If I try and duplicate one folder it works just fine, but multiple just isn't quite working. The code is below

```
display dialog "Please enter your augnet username" default answer "username"
set username to (text returned of result)

set server to "smb://orgs.augsburg.edu"

try
    mount volume server
on error
    display dialog "Either you are already connected, or there was a problem reaching the server. Please disconnect and try again."
end try

delay 3

tell application "Finder"
    set backup to make new folder at folder "ORGS:Information Technology:www:kb_images:Migration Testing:" with properties {name:username}
end tell

set theSelection to choose folder with prompt "Please select what you would like to transfer" with multiple selections allowed

tell application "Finder" to duplicate folder theSelection to backup
```

Any help any of you can give me involving a selection with multiple folders is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `choose folder  … with multiple selections allowed` command will return a list of *alias* objects pointing to folders (unless canceled, of course). Just iterate over that list with a `repeat` loop:

```
set selectedFolders to choose folder with prompt "Yadda" with multiple selections allowed
repeat with selectedFolder in selectedFolders
    -- do something with the folder
end repeat
```

Generally speaking, when in doubt what a command returns, just execute it and look at the output in the AppleScript Editor result window. In your case, it would look something like this:

[image: AppleScript Editor command and output]

– which tells you all you need to know: the returned data is a list (it’s enclosed in braces, `{` and `}`) and contains *alias* objects denoted by their HFS path. As to basics like looping, the [Applescript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362) (reachable through AppleScript Editor’s help menu) has all the details you need.

Finally, I’d recommend using *System Events* instead of Finder for the copy operation, as it is faster and operates in the background.